# Using a half-space with abbreviations in cleveref?

Tags: spacing, cross-referencing, cleveref

I'm using cleveref with abbreviated forms such as Fig. 1, and would like to have them typeset using a thin space/half-space rather than the ordinary non-breaking space. However, I'd only want this after the words that are actually abbreviated, which suggests I may have to do some manual hacking. (I guess I could use `\crefname` with a negative space…?) I know some other similar packages have an option for this, but not cleveref, as far as I can see. Neither do I see any easy way of modifying the behavior of cleveref myself.

Or is this simply a bad idea, typographically? I've read that some typographical books do recommend it, and do think the spacing in `Fig.~1` looks excessive. Then again, I'm not sure what behavior would be desired when describing ranges, for example; is `Figs.\,1 to~3` acceptable? (I guess this latter issue is more of a matter of opinion, though…)

Comment: OK, I guess the idea of manually adding some negative space (which I introduced in my question edit) might be an OK solution. Not posting this as an answer yet, in case someone has a better idea, but… It seems by default only equation and figure are affected, so the solution is simply adding `\crefname{equation}{Eq.\!}{Eqs.\!}`
and `\crefname{figure}{Fig.\!}{Figs.\!}` to my preamble.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As there are no other answers, I'm just going to add the solution I've ended up using (as mentioned in my comment to the question). I simply use `\crefname` for the two abbreviated words in question (as well as any ones I've added myself), with a short negative space (`\!`). In other words, I add the following to my preamble/custom `.sty` file:

```
\crefname{equation}{Eq.\!}{Eqs.\!}
\crefname{figure}{Fig.\!}{Figs.\!}
```

And that's it, really.

Comment: That's probably the best way to go. The other alternative is to use the low-level `\crefformat` customisation command, which lets you take full control over the complete cross-reference format. But unless you're very careful (see the manual) this will break things like `babel` support and automatic theorem names.